# AVI compression with ffmpeg while maintaining alpha channel, to use in Adobe Premiere

Tags: video, ffmpeg, adobe

I am a novice when it comes to handling video conversion/encoding in general, but have spent a few days trying to figure out if ffmpeg, or any other method out there, is able to compress an .avi that has rgb+a. I have been able to get a few files that appear to work when played in VLC, but they wont load into Adobe Premiere to verify that alpha was maintained, and I assume it is a codec issue and/or a pixel format issue, but so far I haven't been able to pinpoint it.

Also, I'm not sure if it's advisable to compress an .avi at all with alpha since it could lead to quality  issues from compression. Some loss of quality is ok if it means reducing file size.

My goal is to convert an avi file to a smaller video file, that isn't multiple GB in size. Currently I have ~8 sec transparent lower thirds file that is about 2GB in size. Simply adjusting bitrate has not done it, as that seems to wipe out the alpha channel and I end up with RGB with a white background. I have tried using a PNG codec, with various different pixel formats. This yielded files that would open in VLC, but not Adobe Premiere. I suspect that this has something to do with the codec, though as to what it is, I have no idea.

Right now, this seems like it may just not be possible. Here are some examples of what I have tried:

`ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -map 0 -c:v png -c:a copy "Compressed.avi"`

--this just creates a file that opens in vlc, but not premiere

`ffmpeg.exe -i "input.avi" -vcodec png -b:v 64k -pix_fmt rgb32 "Compressed.avi"`

--this does the same thing as above, I tried every pixel format on this [list](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2007-May/035617.html) with no success.

`ffmpeg.exe -i "input.avi" -b:v 64k -pix_fmt bgr32 "Compressed.avi"`

--this just results in an avi with a white background, kills alpha.

That is the closest I have come. The bitrate value is likely arbitrary, as I have also tried with and without bitrate modification. I don't know if there is a way to get Premiere to recognize the files that did open in VLC with the PNG codec, or if there is something I am missing, OR if this is just entirely impossible. The output doesn't need to be .avi either, so long as it will open in Premiere.

--
Edit: Requested in the comments, output from ffmpeg -i input.avi

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2020-11-19-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2020-12-09T20:27:57.080928
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1990700 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgra, 1920x1080, 1997313 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

-- Edit 2:
Tried this from the comment and it results in a .mov with preserved alpha but it picks up the white pixel values from text drop shadows, resulting in an outer glow effect instead:

`ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -map 0 -pix_fmt rgba -c:v png -c:a copy "compressed.mov"`

I also tried the following, and I get dropped frames in addition to similar transparency issues in the drop shadow:

`ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -map 0 -pix_fmt rgba -c:v qtrle -c:a copy "compressed.mov"`

Comment: Share the readout of `ffmpeg -i input.avi`

Comment: Added to the main question above!

Answer (score 1):

Save to MOV. Premiere is likely picky about the codecs in AVI files.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -map 0 -pix_fmt rgba -c:v png -c:a copy "Compressed.mov"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this did give me a workable file with alpha, but there was some haze around the lettering (the original has a drop shadow), so it didn't work in the way I needed it to unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

So, updating this, I have found a different solution using Adobe Media Encoder, which isn't ideal, but it gets the job done. I would like to still use ffmpeg if possible, as it would be less resource heavy for simple video automation.

The solution with Adobe Media Encoder is to export as a quicktime mov using the animation codec. Settings:

[Quicktime w/ alpha settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnYIu.png)

This works, but isn't an ideal solution as it requires Adobe Media Encoder. Having a less resource heavy solution would be fantastic, but at least there is *this*, and it does work well with compressing .avi files while doing a good job of maintaining transparency and semi-opaque effects.